# My template do not shows the context_processors's data

Tags: python, django

In the `testMulToM/context_processors.py`, I have a custom function:

```
def custom_proc(request):
    user = {'name': 'allen', 'sex': 'man'}
    return user
```

And I also add to the context processors in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "testMulToM.context_processors.custom_proc",  # add there 
)
```

But when I run my server, and request the url to template, it does not fill the data to template:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

my `app04/index.html` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


User：
{{ name }} : {{ sex }}


</body>
</html>
```

My `app04/views.py`:

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'app04/index.html')
```

---

**EDIT**

I tried return `render(request, 'app04/index.html', {})` , but do not work.

And my python version is 2.7. My django version is 1.11.2

```
python -m django --version
1.11.2
```

Comment: Try adding a context: `return render(request, 'app04/index.html', {})`

Comment: what version of django you are using

Comment: @schwobaseggl I have edit my post, see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS has not been a supported setting since Django 1.8. Assuming you are using a more recent version (which you definitely should be), the list of processors needs to go into the `context_processors` key inside the OPTIONS value for the relevant TEMPLATES dict.

Comment: can you give a link for detail introduce?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates

Comment: Note, that list is there by default; you should just need to append your processor to it.